# Regex pattern matches() method java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to find the regex in java that matches a substring with TTFI within a string TTFI

I'm using /TTFI/ to match the string TTFI in a string such as TTFI1233

When using the folllowing URL http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to check, it results matches() No

The fiddle URL is :http://fiddle.re/e3y2

Thanks,
Nav

Comment: Where do you try to use this regex? AWK, PERL, Java? In Java you would write it as .*TTFI.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slashes are not part of the regular expression, rather language-specific delimiters used in perl, javascript, etc.  Also note that a Java RE requires the *entire* string to match - using `.*TTFI.*` matches your input perfectly.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect. I overlooked the language specific delimiters